# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded used in join function

Tags: python, string, recursion, join

When I try to reverse a string using join function I got the error:

```
string = " ".join(join_reverse(str))
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This is my function:

```
def join_reverse(str):
    string = "".join(join_reverse(str))
    return string
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The error you're getting refers to the fact that you're calling join_reverse repeatedly from within itself without any stop condition.

Comment: Don't use recursion for this, just use `" ".join(string[::-1])`. `str` is a builtin function--don't overwrite it.

Comment: Even I changed the parameter instead of str I got the same error